# Use Bypass markdown library in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, markdown

Like the title, I am trying to use Bypass, an Markdown library, for my android App. However, Since I have migrate from Eclipse to Android Studio, I couldnt figure out how to use the library. I believe I wont be the first person facing this problem. Please help.

the library github: https://github.com/Uncodin/bypass

Answer (score 5):

You need to add a dependency in your app module /build.gradle (or wherever you need to use bypass).

For example: `compile 'com.commit451:bypasses:1.0.1'`

After that you can start using this library in your code.

You have a usage example [here](https://github.com/Uncodin/bypass/blob/master/platform/android/README.md)

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.demoText);
Bypass bypass = new Bypass();
String markdownString = "#Markdown!";
CharSequence string = bypass.markdownToSpannable(markdownString);
text.setText(string);
text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: How can I handle links click events?

Comment: You may use SpannableStringBuilder, URLSpan and ClickableSpan altogether and then set this resultant SpannableStringBuilder to the TextView. @AmrBarakat